# The AccessToken is Changed?

Tags: facebook, oauth, access-token, facebook-oauth

I call facebook api interface, after landing in obtaining accessToken, the facebook api  interface returns accessToken format (format is: accessToken = XXXXXXXXXXX) and the official site description of the format (format is: accessToken = XXXXXXXXXXXX|YYYYYYYYYYY) is not the same, What is the recent facebook interface has changed, or my application for registration has expired? Please Help !!!Thank you very much.

1.the url is :
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=134058973363924&redirect_uri=http://50.0.0.25:11100/portal/HTML/others.portal?a=1&client_secret=3d2796ea5425ace00fe0351200720df8&code=AQAdRuzfxP58uZzzteyBeBK7J_MiN_hywA3NwT-CKZS9fXYnkUd99zmp0VtjsTLpyRgtGgaeiHVrBtwXRdvjMI1YLDOTBq3qrtNFJwcqun8Wpgu6SQCKDQvqJhZqCdAZUSAtjKgY1Xs5V_aayzYivUyGvZE8Ry9Wb4WeNvF_HIaeKZ6Cdwvc62V1hpopamqKw9g

2.But the facebook api return access token format is:
access_token=AAADKf6X8LHYBAEZCa1sDqK40KZBTEQmDU0bOmJaq0AIwGJVImtkMWrYCrq8568mMpShFI44KObs6MxYNISvQQZB7HObbywtFOMRNL1mrgZDZD

I expect an access token format like: 
access_token=116122545078207|2.1vGZASUSFMHeMVgQ_9P60Q__.3600.1272535200-500880518|QXlU1XfJR1mMagHLPtaMjJzFZp4

But return access token format is:
access_token=AAADKf6X8LHYBAEZCa1sDqK40KZBTEQmDU0bOmJaq0AIwGJVImtkMWrYCrq8568mMpShFI44KObs6MxYNISvQQZB7HObbywtFOMRNL1mrgZDZD

please tell me why?

Comment: Why did you ask this question again?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you share the question's answer to me?

Comment: The access token format has been changed to a encrypted one now after the oauth2.0 enabled for applications.. So the access token is coming in this way.. Refer the latest documents on this and make the necessary changes. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth2-https-migration/

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm going now!:)

Comment: This shouldn't affect any applications except those which were using XMPP login, the docs for the chat API explain how to use the new access tokens with XMPP login

Comment: The old login mode is unused?

Answer (score 1):

We can create two type of `accesstoken` in FB. If you go with GUI you have to select the app and give permission to that. Then click `generate accesstoken`. You will get **2 hours** validity accesstoken. In another way you can able to get 60 days token. To generate **60 days** Accesstoken you have to follow the below steps:

> `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=306419042868034&redirect_uri=http://localhost:53568/&client_secret=4692eb6841c8ff0474cd81b05949f67f&code=AQCCgfgp7Xi7fSqK5TqxentrBDFkIk9_EVcWudVEiduGyS-p_xoec9A2h5Q5g-QMqwyuz48q6z_X06ydiEG4PX9WdCZ-uWzr6C8QI7wY_OUqeIbggxC_u2j8p1jXLlYvz7ujYDTZNZ_sLBj2_Clc0Ti8I9ULzr_EDwg04yq1cQnKBPk9mvhqcfFA99ZGHte2Cuq3632-N60zXPr6ri_5ttA_3kJbbQS5D885qMSGKZaOzSOr6LplETqZZjhsjbVpilXg3QkgB4Do1nfWhlIM-thz2gg_caFL6hIgZKlUdGqtQ-1Pv7XX8EMAVlqbZCq6o_c#_=_&state=anytexthere`